# how to set default value as checked in checkbox in odoo

Tags: odoo

I'm inheriting res_config_settings_views and i want the checkbox under analytics groups to load as checked on every page reload i.e., i want to set the value of analytics accounting checkbox as true as default.

I have tried setting it to true via inheriting model by defining as `group_analytic_accounting = fields.Boolean(string='', default=True)` in the py file and also i have tried setting it as default from xml file as `<field name="group_analytic_accounting">{'default_group_analytic_accounting': 'True'}</field>`

Both of them turned out to be failed attempts. Any help or guidance here is much appreciated.

P.S: Odoo Version is 12

[I have a uploaded a image for reference and rounded up checkbox is the one i want to be checked as default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvgUd.png)

Thank you

edit:
below is the xml code

P.S: I'm inheriting res_config_settings_views (Odoo Community->addons->account->views). I want to modify just the analytic div and load the checkbox as checked in default

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='analytic']" position="replace">
                <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container" id="analytic">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 o_setting_box" title="Allows you to use the analytic accounting." groups="account.group_account_user">
                        <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                            <field name="group_analytic_accounting"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                            <label for="group_analytic_accounting"/>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                Track costs &amp; revenues by project, department, etc.
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-group" attrs="{'invisible': [('group_analytic_accounting', '=', False)]}">
                                <div class="mt16" id="analytic_account_link">
                                    <button name="%(analytic.action_analytic_account_form)d" icon="fa-arrow-right"
                                            type="action" string="Analytic Accounts" class="btn-link"/>
                                </div>
                                <div id="analytic_account_groups_link">
                                    <button name="%(analytic.account_analytic_group_action)d" icon="fa-arrow-right"
                                            type="action" string="Analytic Account Groups" class="btn-link"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

below is the python code

```
class Account(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    group_analytic_accounting = fields.Boolean(string='Test Analytic Accounting', implied_group='analytic.group_analytic_accounting', default=True, required=True, change_default=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `var = fields.Boolean(string='', default=True)` does n't works try putting a compute field or call a function from the field.

```
def function_name(self):
   self.var = True
```

Comment: actually i'm inheriting and re-using the same field and when i try to keep inside a def it says field is not defined and as a novice i don't know how that works. I'm trying to figure out this stuff but it's too confusing. Finally though i managed to remove the whole checkbox as my assignment was getting late but i really would love to know how to make the checkbox checked as default. thanks for taking your time and helping out

Answer (score 0):

```
var = fields.Boolean(string='', default=True)
```

This code should work.
Can we see the entire class?

Comment: I have edited the question now and included the details you asked for